# Bash: Fail to use find -exec

Tags: bash, macos, rsync, scp, find-util

When using `scp` or `rsync` I often fail to deal with 'Argument list too long' error. When having to `mv` or `rm`, I have no problem to use `find` and `xargs` but I fail to understand how to use `find` and `-exec` despite all the SE posts on the subject. Consider the following issue...

I tried

```
$scp /Path/to/B* Me@137.92.4.152:/Path/to/

-bash: /usr/bin/scp: Argument list too long
```

So I tried

```
$find . -name "/Path/to/B*" -exec scp "{}" Me@137.92.4.152:/Path/to/ '\;'

find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

so I tried

```
$find . -name "/Path/to/B*" -exec scp "{}" Me@137.92.4.152:/Path/to/ ';'

find: ./.gnupg: Permission denied
find: ./.subversion/auth: Permission denied
```

So I tried

```
$sudo find . -name "/Path/to/B*" -exec scp "{}" Me@137.92.4.152:/Path/to/ ';'
```

and nothing happen onces I enter my password

I am on Mac OSX version 10.11.3, Terminal version 2.6.1

Comment: why don't you just copy the directory, not all files inside it? "scp - r" would do the job

Comment: Sorry, my example was bad as I selected all the files. I changed the example to make explicit that I don't want to copy all the files. What I typically do now is that I `mkdir`, `find ... |xargs mv ..` the files, then `scp -r` the dir, `mv` the files back and `rm -r` the directory which is rather silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[R. Saban's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44462319/45375) solves your *primary* problem:

- **`-name` only accepts a *filename* pattern**, not a *path* pattern.
- Alternatively, you could simply use the `-path` primary instead of the `-name` primary.

As for **using as few invocations of `scp` as possible** - each of which requires specifying a password by default:

- As an alternative, consider bypassing the use of `scp` altogether, as suggested in [Eric Renouf's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44462935/45375).
- While `find`'s `-exec` primary allows using terminator `+` in lieu of `;` (which must be passed as `';'` or `\;` to prevent the *shell* from interpreting `;` as a command terminator) for passing as many filenames as will fit on a single command line (a built-in `xargs`, in a manner of speaking), this is NOT an option here, because use of `+` requires that placeholder `{}` come *last* on the command line, immediately before `+`.
- However, since you're on macOS, you can use BSD `xarg`'s nonstandard `-J` option for placing the placeholder *anywhere* on the command line, while still passing as many arguments as possible at once (using BSD `find`'s nonstandard `-print0` option in combination with `xargs`'s nonstandard `-0` option ensures that all filenames are passed as-is, even if they have embedded spaces, for instance):

```
find . -path "/Path/to/B*" -print0 | xargs -0 -J {} scp {} Me@137.92.4.152:/Path/to/
```

Now you will at most be prompted a *few* times: one prompt for every batch of arguments, as required to accommodate all arguments while observing the max. command-line length with the fewest number of calls possible.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT after your update:

```
find "/Path/to" -maxdepth 1 -name "B*" -exec scp {} Me@137.92.4.152:/Path/to/ \;
```

Comment: Oh... I silly I am. Just had to not put the whole path in the name. I now have to enter my password at every single file. Do you happen to also have a solution for that?

Comment: You can accept this answer and open another one for your new issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that wouldn't require multiple `scp` connections (and therefore password entries) would be to tar on one side and untar on the other like:

```
find /Path/to -maxdepth 1 -name 'B*' -print0 | tar -c --null -T - | ssh ME@137.92.4.152 tar -x -C /Path/to
```

assuming your version of `find` supports `-print0` and the like.  It works by printing out null terminated list of files from `find` and telling `tar` to read its list of files from stdin (`-T -`) treating the list as null terminated (`--null`) and create a new archive (`-c`).  By default, `tar` will write to stdout.

So then we'll pipe that archive to an `ssh` command to the target host.  That will read the output of the previous command on its stdin, so we'll use `tar` there to extract (`-x`) the archive into the given directory (`-C /Path/to`)